# Unreal Engine 5.3.2 Localization Dashboard not working

Tags: game-development, unreal-engine5, unreal

I followed tutorials in youtube to implement the Localization, but its not working, I translated something to test and compiled all the lenguage one per one and sometimes all in the same time, but the translation never appear in the widget preview, for exemple, and never appear in the editor settings too. No erros appears when i compile, Unreal says is a success.
[Here is a image of my Localization Dashbord screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8npO3.png)
[Here another part of my Localization Dashbord screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy3Nl.png)
[My widget preview language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz4sg.png)

I tried several tutorials and read all comments on the videos, but I didn't find any solution idea to my problem.
I think the problemen is the "Loading Policy", he is setted in "Never" and I cant change it

Answer (score 0):

In order to include a culture into the packaged version of the game, you need to go into Project Settings → Packaging, and select the cultures you want your game to support in the “Localizations To Package” (you may need to expand the settings to see it), like the picture below:

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I followed your steps and not solve my problem

Comment: Oh wait, I try to execute the game in "Selected Viewport" when I execute in "Standalone Game" its work. Thanks. But it still not showing nothing in "Widget Preview Language"